# Will this SQL injection prevention work in theory?

Tags: php, security

I plan to prevent SQL injections by using the the $variable and route it to a  function that will scan the $variable for any sql commands or any attempts of injections. I will also make a list of common sql commands that people would use inject so it would be detected.

Note: I previously asked a similar question but this time I have a theory I managed to think ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and secure way to prevent SQL injection is to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on any untrusted data (eg: $_GET or $_POST). It will escape any special characters so the query will be safe.

If you use mysqli, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

More about SQL injection and how can you protect yourself against it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

So, your plan it's not the best way to do it. It unnecessarly complicates things.

Answer (score 3):

No. Blacklisting will inevitably give false positives and almost certainly give false negatives.

Use [bound parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and let the database deal with it for you.